# Simple C code snippets

Tags: c

I have a great difficulty in understanding the printed values of these 2 source codes.

```
#include<stdio.h>
    void a(void){
    int a;
    a++;
    printf("%d\n",a);
}

int main(void){
    a(); 
    a();
    a();
    return 0;
}
```

Why does this code print out "1  2  3 " ,while the second one:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void a(void){
    int a;
    a++;
    printf("%d\n",a);
}

int main(void){
    int b;
    printf("%d\n",b);
    a(); 
    a();
    a();
    return 0;
}
```

Prints out: " 0, garbage value, same garbage value +1, same garbage value +2 ".

Shouldn't any uninitialized object in the main function (or any other functon ) be assigned a random (garbage) value?

UPDATE: I feel that the explanation "the variables are uninitialized so they can have any remaining values from other programs so -> UB" is not sufficient. I can copy-paste the same source code 100 times and still get the printed value of 0. I am using gcc 4.4.3.

Comment: Undefined values. Whatever is on the stack is what you get. It's different in the second case since your stack changed by adding a local variable in `main`. It just so happens in the first case the value on the stack at the address of `a` is `0`. The `0` could be just randomly `0`.

Comment: In the first case, it may be that the compiler has decided you are "initializing" the value for `a` at `0` and so you get a reasonable set of values.  This behavior would be compiler-specific.  Please add the compiler you are using to your question.

Comment: @abiessu; So isn't that UB?

Comment: @haccks: yes.  I have no disagreement with the designation of the behavior.  My intent is to weed out the potential of the compiler (possibly) making decisions for the programmer and thus (potentially) encouraging or discouraging bad programming practices...

Comment: @abiessu; Yes. Now agreed. But It is better to stick with C standard rather than compiler specification.

Comment: @abiessu I am using gcc 4.4.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value of uninitialized automatic variables is indeterminate and so if you don't talk about a specific compiler on a specific machine with a specific set of flags then it is really unpredictable. Even if you talk about a very specific platform and settings you still may not get reproducible results.

In some very specific situations you can make predictions and the [presentation Deep C](http://www.slideshare.net/olvemaudal/deep-c) talks about this in general and covers this specific case around slide `71`.

On modern systems automatic variables will often be allocated on the stack and you may get the same memory location and therefore you would then see three consecutive values. But you should not rely on this behavior and using uninitialized variables is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and the results are unpredictable.

The [C99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) tell us in section `6.7.8` *Initialization* paragraph *10* that:

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate.

and tell us in the definitions of `indeterminate value`:

> either an unspecified value or a trap representation

**Update**

What is undefined behavior? In the strictest sense it is behavior the C standard does not impose requirements on, it is construct of the standard. It is defined in the draft standard in section `3.4.3`:

> behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data,
>   for which this International Standard imposes no requirements

and has the following note:

> Possible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable results, to behaving during translation or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message), to terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance of a diagnostic message).

at the end of the day it is a trade off between designing an efficient language and a safe one, which is paraphrased from [What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior #1/3](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html).

Here are more links to better understanding undefined behavior:

- [Philosophy behind Undefined Behavior](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99692/philosophy-behind-undefined-behavior)
- [Why Language Designers Tolerate Undefined Behavior](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/why-language-designers-tolerate-undefine/240165466)

Comment: So undefined behaviour actually comes from the fact that it can have different results based on the compiler, machine, flags, optimization?

Comment: @Dragos276 those are some of the major variables, one could probably produce a test case using an [online compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916000/online-c-compiler-and-evaluator) which was consistent and dig into the assembly and determine why but what do you hope to gain from that?

Comment: I was trying to understand the behaviour of the 2 source codes and what does UB actually mean besides "random assigned number from memory." Are the machine's own specific mnemonics responsible for this random behavior then?

Comment: Also, I have read the Deep C slides and that is where my question stems from.

Comment: @Dragos276 I added some more details to my answer, I will try and add more details later on and probably links to other SO questions that cover this topic. It could be helpful to check out some of the highest votes question under the [undefined behavior tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/undefined-behavior?sort=votes&pageSize=50) as well.

Comment: @Dragos276:  "undefined behavior" simply means that the compiler is not required to handle the situation in any particular way (either because handling it the "right" way is too difficult or impossible for a given architecture, or because there is no "right" way at all).  Depending on the issue, the compiler may halt translation with a diagnostic, finish translation with a diagnostic, finish translation with no diagnostic, etc.  You may get unexpected output, memory may get overwritten, the executable may crash, or everything may appear to run correctly.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does this code print out "1 2 3 "

It invokes undefined behavior. Any thing could happen. Using an uninitialized variable invokes UB.

> Shouldn't any uninitialized object in the main function (or any other functon ) be assigned a random (garbage) value?

Yes. But that garbage value could be any thing. you can't predict it.

Comment: Come on. This is not an explanation. You can do better.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker; Yah. I am doing so.

Comment: @abiessu; Then please post your answer. I will learn how to post a *better* answer.

Answer (score 2):

`int a;` In first code you haven't initialized `a` which means it contains garbage values in it. Both the above codes snippets could behave differently printing garbage values.

> An uninitialized variable is a variable that is declared but is not set to a definite known value before it is used. It will have `some value`, but not a predictable one. As such, it is a programming error and a common source of bugs in software.

Answer (score 2):

Since all values are uninitialized they could contain anything.

So your output is unpredictable because you cannot know what value the variables have.

This is what is called undefined behavior.

Comment: So what are you saying is that the term "undefined behavior" comes from the fact that the values of the declared variables can sometimes have 0 or random values depending on the structure of the source code?

Comment: Well the first part of your sentence is correct. But the fact that it is undefined does not come from the structure of the code but from the fact that your are accessing memory without knowing it's content.

Comment: @Dragos276: the variables are uninitialized.  This means that they have no value to begin with, and whatever existed in the memory location they are assigned to is the values they start with.

Answer (score 1):

It's both undefined bahaviour. It just happens to be 0 for the local variable in main and also 0 for the local variable in the first example. And then a random value at the shifted local variable location for a in the second example (shifted due to a local variable in main).

Memory pages are usually zero'd when retrieved from the OS, so it's most likely the stack footprint of the language runtime or some other pre-main code. Therefore being seemingly predictable for you at repeated runs. It's possibly completely different on different machines/compilers etc.